# List with unequal length matrices to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a mass spec list of 2701, with unequal length matrices at each point (x and y are the same but the number of them varies) that indicate the M/Z value and the Abundance, so X and Y at each point 1:2701. Therefore, this is essentially 3D.  The problem is that I cannot get it into a dataframe to view all numbers.  Maybe something like this or the transverse;

X_value Y_value
1

```
60       32
26       37
 3        4
```

2

```
 6       14
 10       3
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, your_list))`

Comment: Is the problem that you want to retain information about index in the list a row originally came from? What is the desired output?

Comment: Yes desired output is simply being able to see all dimension in one dataframe.  I'm new here so I messed up the formatting in the OP. Look where I have x_value and y_value then the number 1 for all three of the x and y.  That is similar to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. `imap` maps across each list element and adds a column with the index, and then `bind_rows` combines into one data frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mspec <- list(
  tibble(x = c(60, 26, 3), y = c(32, 37, 4)),
  tibble(x = c(6, 10), y = c(14, 3))
)

mspec %>%
  imap(~ mutate(.x, index = .y)) %>%
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>       x     y index
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1   60.   32.     1
#> 2   26.   37.     1
#> 3    3.    4.     1
#> 4    6.   14.     2
#> 5   10.    3.     2
```

Created on 2018-04-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Do you know why I'd be getting this error?                                  > mspec %>%
+     imap(~ mutate(.x, index = .y)) %>%
+     bind_rows()
Error in apply(x[["ll"]], 2, max, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
>

Comment: are any of the data frames empty/have no rows? try `table(map_int(mspec, nrow))` It helps to `dput` the first few elements, truncating them if they are too big as well, so we can see if the structure is the same as the example list i gave.